# Vue.js - Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

I have a Vue.js project which was working normally until a few minutes ago. I was in the middle of trying to add a new small piece of functionality when `npm run build` stopped working, with the `Syntax Error` you see below. I spent time reading it over, but it seems to me that there are no clues given as to where the `Unexpected token` actually is, other than that it's in App.vue.

I suspect I can probably eventually get it working by just taking out code until I figure out what it's choking on, but what's the preferred way to deal with these error messages? They seem not helpful, and pulling out code every time I get a `Syntax Error` is going to be much slower than knowing where the error is immediately.

```
| building for production...
Starting to optimize CSS...
Processing css/app.b78de1b1e52d045850f3f8ef25eab789.css...
Processed css/app.b78de1b1e52d045850f3f8ef25eab789.css, before: 2077, after: 2009, ratio: 96.73%
Hash: 463db738399a4df0bc89
Version: webpack 2.6.1
Time: 7211ms
                                           Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                  js/app.46d986e313fa2c015cd0.js    5.62 kB       0  [emitted]  app
               js/vendor.bf7e840e23d2fcdbebe0.js     141 kB       1  [emitted]  vendor
             js/manifest.c323c0be7462a1c8da87.js    1.51 kB       2  [emitted]  manifest
    css/app.b78de1b1e52d045850f3f8ef25eab789.css    2.01 kB       0  [emitted]  app
              js/app.46d986e313fa2c015cd0.js.map      26 kB       0  [emitted]  app
css/app.b78de1b1e52d045850f3f8ef25eab789.css.map    4.13 kB       0  [emitted]  app
           js/vendor.bf7e840e23d2fcdbebe0.js.map     974 kB       1  [emitted]  vendor
         js/manifest.c323c0be7462a1c8da87.js.map    14.6 kB       2  [emitted]  manifest
                        ..\..\templates\app.html  598 bytes          [emitted]

ERROR in ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-59c95520"}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (72:13)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:2231:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:613:10)
    at Parser.pp.expect (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:607:28)
    at Parser.parseObj (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:3871:16)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1815:19)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:3800:24)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1725:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1702:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1647:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1630:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1607:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyValue (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:2008:89)
    at Parser.parseObj (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:3895:14)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1815:19)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:3800:24)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1725:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1702:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1647:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1630:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1607:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprList (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:2175:22)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseSubscripts (C:\path_to_project\client\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:1751:35)
 @ ./src/App.vue 8:2-170
 @ ./src/main.js
```

Here is App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="toolbar" v-on-clickaway="disableSongToolbar">
      <div id="toolbar__left">
        <a class="ui-text toolbar__option" href="/">Rhymecraft</a>
        <div class="ui-text toolbar__option"
             :class="{ toolbar__option_active: songToolbarActive }"
             @click="toggleSongToolbarDropdown()">
          Song
        </div>
        <div class="ui-text toolbar__option">Line</div>
        <div class="ui-text toolbar__option">Help</div>
      </div>
      <div id="toolbar__right">
        <a class="ui-text toolbar__option" href="/logout">Log out</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="toolbar-dropdowns">
      <div id="toolbar-dropdowns__song" v-show="songToolbarActive">
        <div class="ui-text toolbar__option toolbar-dropdown-option toolbar-dropdown-not-last-option"
             @click="createNewSong">Create new song</div>
        <div class="ui-text toolbar__option toolbar-dropdown-option"
            @click="displayListOfUsersSongs">Load song</div>
        <div class="ui-text toolbar__option toolbar-dropdown-option"
             v-if="song.hasOwnProperty('id')"
            @click="displayConfirmDeleteSong = true">Delete current song</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modals" :class="{ modals-active: modalActive }">
      <div id="song-loader" v-show="displaySongLoader">
        <div id="song-loader-header" class="ui-text">Load Song</div>
        <div class="ui-text song-loader__item song-loader__selectable-item" v-for="song in songs" @click="loadSong(song.id)">{{ song.name }}</div>
        <div class="ui-text song-loader__item" v-if="songs.length === 0 || !songs[0].hasOwnProperty('id')">You do not have any songs.</div>
        <div id="song-loader__cancel" class="ui-text" @click="displaySongLoader = false">Cancel</div>
      </div>
      <div id="confirm-delete-song" v-show="displayConfirmDeleteSong">
        <div id="confirm-delete-song__header" class="ui-text">Delete Song</div>
        <div id="confirm-delete-song__cancel" class="ui-text" @click="displayConfirmDeleteSong = false">Cancel</div>
        <div id="confirm-delete-song__spacer"></div>
        <div id="confirm-delete-song__confirm" class="ui-text" @click="deleteCurrentSong">Confirm</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="song-area">
      <div id="song">
        <div v-for="line in song.lines" class="song-line">
          <div v-for="spanOfTime in line.spansOfTime"
               class="ui-text span-of-time span-of-time--4"
               :id="spanOfTime.id"
               @click="currentlySelectedSpanOfTime = spanOfTime.id; console.log(spanOfTime.id)">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  mixins: [ clickaway ],
  data: function () {
    return {
      songToolbarActive: false,
      displaySongLoader: false,
      song: [],
      songs: [],
      displayConfirmDeleteSong: false,
      currentlySelectedSpanOfTime: -1
    }
  },
  computed: {
    modalActive: function () {
      if (this.displaySongLoader) {
        return true
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSongToolbarDropdown: function () {
      this.songToolbarActive = !this.songToolbarActive
    },
    disableSongToolbar: function () {
      if (this.songToolbarActive) {
        this.songToolbarActive = false
      }
    },
    createNewSong: function () {
      this.$http.post('/song/create').then(response => {
        this.song = response.data.song
      }, response => {
        // error callback
      })
    },
    displayListOfUsersSongs: function () {
      this.$http.get('/songs').then(response => {
        this.songs = response.data.songs
        this.displaySongLoader = true
      }, response => {
        // error callback
      })
    },
    loadSong: function (songId) {
      this.displaySongLoader = false
      this.$http.get('/song/' + songId).then(response => {
        this.song = response.data.song
      }, response => {
        this.song = []
      })
    },
    deleteCurrentSong: function () {
      this.displayConfirmDeleteSong = false
      this.$http.post('/song/' + this.song.id + '/delete').then(response => {
        this.song = []
      }, response => {
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
div#modals {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
div.modals-active {
  z-index: 1;
}
div#song-loader {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85);
}
div#song-loader-header {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  background-color:rgb(60,63,65);
}
div.song-loader__item {
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 10px;
  color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
}
div.song-loader__selectable-item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 190);
}
div#song-loader__cancel {
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
div#song-area {
  height: 100%;
}
div#song {
  width: 608px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
div.span-of-time {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 29px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
}
div.span-of-time--4 {
  width: 37px;
}
div#app {
  height: 100%
}
div#toolbar {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #282828;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgb(85,85,85);
}
div#toolbar__left {
  display: inline-block;
}
div#toolbar__right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.ui-text {
  color: #BBBBBB;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Martel Sans', sans-serif;
  cursor: default;

  /* noselect */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
div#toolbar-dropdowns {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.toolbar__option {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 2px 5px 0px 5px;
}
.toolbar__option:hover {
  color: rgb(225,225,225);
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.toolbar__option_active {
  background-color: rgb(75,110,175);
}
div#toolbar-dropdowns__song {
  margin-left: 86px;
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid dimgray;
}
div.toolbar-dropdown-not-last-option {
  border-bottom: 1px solid dimgray;
}
div.toolbar-dropdown-option {
  cursor: default;
  width: 181px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}
div.toolbar-dropdown-option:hover {
  background-color: rgb(75,110,175);
}
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
</style>
```

---

Update: I found the error by cutting out code until `npm run build` worked again. The problem was that I had created a conditional class with a dash in its name, but hadn't surrounded the class name with single-quotes. So instead of `:class="{ 'modals-active': modalActive }"` I had `:class="{ modals-active: modalActive }"`.

However, I didn't ask this question to solve this particular problem, but to know if there's any way to use these error messages to get to the problem quicker. The actual problem was on line 29 of the `.vue` template file, but the error message seems to indicate that the error is on line 72.

Comment: Please paste your code...

Comment: where is line 72 ?

Comment: I found the source of the problem by cutting out code until I found what was causing the issue, so I'm taking down the code from the question, as the question is more about what to do with these unhelpful error messages.

Comment: line 72 is the line immediately before the "computed: {" line.

Comment: Actually I'm going to keep the code up.

Comment: My initial thought when I see that error is that the ES2015 transpiler (`babel`) is not being applied somewhere. When using webpack `babel-loader` usually isn't applied to the `node_modules` folder, so the first thing I would do is check if a publisher has published ES2015 code without pre-transpiling

Comment: @craig_h "the first thing I would do is check if a publisher has published ES2015 code without pre-transpiling" How would I do that?

Comment: @NathanWailes if you're familiar with ES2015 you can take a look at the source code for the main entry file. Things to look for in particular are [import statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You will then need to add a rule to your webpack config to apply `babel-loader` to that particular package.

Comment: @craig_h Thanks for the tips. Given that the stack trace seems to be saying the error is happening while running code in the `vue-template-es2015-compiler` `node_modules` package, which would seem to suggest an error within a `.vue` template that is preventing the compiler from working properly, what about the error/stack-trace led you to suspect that it may be un-transpiled JavaScript within another `node_modules` package?

Comment: would have been nice if you had answered your own question in a separate answer post, not within the question ;-)

Comment: @jasie done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error by cutting out code until `npm run build` worked again. The problem was that I had created a conditional class with a dash in its name, but hadn't surrounded the class name with single-quotes. So instead of `:class="{ 'modals-active': modalActive }"` I had `:class="{ modals-active: modalActive }"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which turned out to be this small code snippet:

```js
item = {
  ...item,
  ...this.files[file]
};
```

My best guess is that webpack doesn't like the object spread operator, as that was introduced in ES2018.